# Exact equivalent of `b'...'.decode("utf-8", "backslashreplace")` in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, encoding, backwards-compatibility

In Python 3.5+ `.decode("utf-8", "backslashreplace")` is a pretty good option for dealing with  partially-Unicode, partially-some-unknown-legacy-encoding binary strings.  Valid UTF-8 sequences will be decoded and invalid ones will be preserved as escape sequences.  For instance

```
>>> print(b'\xc2\xa1\xa1'.decode("utf-8", "backslashreplace"))
¡\xa1
```

This loses the distinction between `b'\xc2\xa1\xa1'` and `b'\xc2\xa1\\xa1'`, but if you're in the "just get me *something* not too lossy that I can fix up by hand later" frame of mind, that's probably OK.

However, this is a new feature in Python 3.5.  The program I'm working on also needs to support 3.4 and 2.7.  In those versions, it throws an exception:

```
>>> print(b'\xc2\xa1\xa1'.decode("utf-8", "backslashreplace"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
TypeError: don't know how to handle UnicodeDecodeError in error callback
```

I have found an approximation, but not an exact equivalent:

```
>>> print(b'\xc2\xa1\xa1'.decode("latin1")
...       .encode("ascii", "backslashreplace").decode("ascii"))
\xc2\xa1\xa1
```

It is very important that the behavior not depend on the interpreter version.  Can anyone advise a way to get *exactly* the Python 3.5 behavior in 2.7 and 3.4?

(Older versions of either 2.x or 3.x do not need to work.  Monkey patching `codecs` is totally acceptable.)

Comment: "Changed in version 3.5: The 'backslashreplace' error handlers now works with decoding and translating." -- Did you mean 3.4 or 3.5?

Comment: @JoshLee  I was sloppy and only tested it in 3.5. I do in fact need something that works with 3.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I attempted a more complete backport of the [cpython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d6e2f26f3f7c62a4ddbf668027d3ba27cb0e1eca/Python/codecs.c#L859)

This handles both `UnicodeDecodeError` (from `.decode()`) as well as `UnicodeEncodeError` from `.encode()` and `UnicodeTranslateError` from `.translate()`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import codecs


def _bytes_repr(c):
    """py2: bytes, py3: int"""
    if not isinstance(c, int):
        c = ord(c)
    return '\\x{:x}'.format(c)


def _text_repr(c):
    d = ord(c)
    if d >= 0x10000:
        return '\\U{:08x}'.format(d)
    else:
        return '\\u{:04x}'.format(d)


def backslashescape_backport(ex):
    s, start, end = ex.object, ex.start, ex.end
    c_repr = _bytes_repr if isinstance(ex, UnicodeDecodeError) else _text_repr
    return ''.join(c_repr(c) for c in s[start:end]), end


codecs.register_error('backslashescape_backport', backslashescape_backport)

print(b'\xc2\xa1\xa1after'.decode('utf-8', 'backslashescape_backport'))
print(u'\u2603'.encode('latin1', 'backslashescape_backport'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's "backslashreplace" btw, not "backslashescape"

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own error handler.  Here's a solution that I tested on Python 2.7, 3.3 and 3.6:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import codecs
import sys

print(sys.version)

def myreplace(ex):
    # The error handler receives the UnicodeDecodeError, which contains arguments of the
    # string and start/end indexes of the bad portion.
    bstr,start,end = ex.object,ex.start,ex.end

    # The return value is a tuple of Unicode string and the index to continue conversion.
    # Note: iterating byte strings returns int on 3.x but str on 2.x
    return u''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(c if isinstance(c,int) else ord(c))
                    for c in bstr[start:end]),end

codecs.register_error('myreplace',myreplace)
print(b'\xc2\xa1\xa1ABC'.decode("utf-8", "myreplace"))
```

Output:

> ```
> C:\>py -2.7 test.py
> 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
> ¡\xa1ABC
>
> C:\>py -3.3 test.py
> 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
> ¡\xa1ABC
>
> C:\>py -3.6 test.py
> 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
> ¡\xa1ABC
> ```